# sobreposição de divs, porem deixando um topo sem ser sobreposto

Tags: html, css

Estou conseguindo sobrepor as divs mas nao consigo colocar um nav em cima que não seja sobreposto.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

h1,h2{
    color:#ccc;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
    background-color:blue;
    z-index: 1;
    position:fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top:0px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.div2{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
 <h1>Conteudo div1</h1>
</div>
<div class="div2">
 <h2>Conteudo div2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Se possível coloque o seu código já com o HTML com a NAV e o CSS dela

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vc consegue resolver isso colocando a primeira `div` Azul com 100% da altura menos a altura da própria `Nav`, para isso use `height:calc(100% - 50px)` 50px é a altura da `Nav`. Faça a mesma coisa com altura da `div` Vermelha.

Na `div` Vermelha além do ajuste da altura use `position:sticky` e não `position:relative`, e nela coloque um `top:50px`, 50px é a altura da `Nav`, e pronto nada encobrira ou ficara com o conteúdo escondido abaixo da `Nav`.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

h1,h2{
    color:#ccc;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
    background-color:blue;
    z-index: 1;
    position:fixed;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: 100%;
    top:50px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.div2{
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: red;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 100vh;
    top: 50px;
}
nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:50px
}
```

```html
<nav>
    MINHA NAV!
</nav>
<div class="div1">
    <h1>Conteudo div1</h1>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <h2>Conteudo div2</h2>
</div>
```

***OBS:*** `position:sticky` não funciona no IE https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky